# how to get last values of email after the @

Tags: php

i am trying to determine the best way to determine whether an email address is an  outlook or hotmail address.

i therefore need to collect the values after the @

i.e

```
testemail@outlook.com
```

caputure the @

however this will not work in all instance as

this email address is valid:

```
"foo\@bar"@iana.org
```

i read that a solution could be to explode it, i.e:

```
$string = "user@domain.com";

$explode = explode("@",$string);

array_pop($explode);

$newstring = join('@', $explode);

echo $newstring;
```

this solution seems bit long and only captures the first values

would really appreciate some help

Comment: Have you considered using a regular expression instead?

Comment: @belwood Mallet to crack a nut in this case I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

if You explode This :

```
$string = "user@domain.com";

$explode = explode("@",$string);
```

it Will be :

```
$explode[0] = user
$explode[1] = domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use array_reverse() ti pick the last value of email:

```
<?php
$email='exa@mple@hotmail.com';
$explode_email=explode('@',$email);
$reversed_array=array_reverse($explode_email);
$mailserver=explode('.',$reversed_array[0]);

echo $mailserver[0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just keep it simple and test if either value exists in the string using strpos() or stripos().

```
if ( FALSE !== stripos($string, 'outlook') {
    // outlook exists in the string
}

if ( FALSE !== stripos($string, 'hotmail') {
    // hotmail exists in the string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend matching with a regular expression.

```
if (preg_match("/\@hotmail.com$/", $email)) {
    echo "on hotmail";
} else if (preg_match("/\@outlook.com$/", $email)) {
    echo "on outlook";
} else {
    echo "different domain";
}
```

Additionally, if you want to capture full domain to variable, you can do it like this:

```
$matches = [];
if (preg_match("/^.*\@([\w\.]+)$/", $email, $matches)) {
    echo "Domain: " . $matches[1];
} else {
    echo "not a valid email address.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this will be easy for you to understand.**

```
<?php
$emailAddress = 'mailbox@hotmail.com'; //Email Address

$emailStringArray = explode('@',$emailAddress);  // take apart the email string.

$host = $emailStringArray[1];  //last string after @ . $emailStringArray[0] = Mailbox  & $emailStringArray[1] = host
if($host == "hotmail.com" || $host == "outlook.com"){
//matches to outlook.com or hotmail.com
}
else{
    //Does not match to outlook.com or hotmail.com
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$emailAddress = 'example\@sometext\@someothertext@hotmail.com';

$explodedEmail = explode('@', $emailAddress);
$emailServerHostName = end($explodedEmail);
$emailServerNameExploded = explode('.', $emailServerHostName);
$emailServerName = $emailServerNameExploded[0];

echo $emailServerName;
```